# zend form - Element Label in two line

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am extremely new to Zend Framework, In registration form, i need label text in two line. For Example:- In the case First name, I need to display like below:

```
First
Name:
```

How can i implement this? Please anyone help me!!!

Comment: Could you clarify your question, since I don't know what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, That is i need to display a text box label in two line (I want to add a <br> tag inside one label text , Example: First<br> Name:)...

Answer (score 12):

By default, input fields labels are being escaped by `Zend_View_Helper_FormLabel`. However, you can easy switch this off:

```
$yourTextInputElement->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);
```

This way you can use labels as e.g. `$yourTextInputElement->setLabel('First <br/> name');`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this nifty solution ?

http://jsfiddle.net/J67GD/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use `Description` decorator, or subclass one of other standard ZF decorators.

[Yanick's CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905284/zend-form-element-label-in-two-line/4905398#4905398)  might be a good choice too, depending what are you trying to do.